# How to filter and order collection in C#?

Tags: c#

Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var crView = db.CRCases.ToList();
    return View(crView);
}
```

Would like to filter like we have in sql statement using `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`.
Is there any good reference on how to apply it?

Comment: There is an `OrderBy()` method for lists.

Comment: Use [LinqToSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: And Where() to do a selection.

Answer (score 0):

linq is your friend here.

you can do

```
crView = crView.Where(x => x.yourPredicate).OrderBy( y => y.OrderClause);
```

Answer (score 0):

CRCases should be a `DBSet<T>`. You can use `LinQ` like this :

```
db.CRCases.Where(x => x.TheProperty =xxx).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ = Language Integrated Query.

This have two different notations:

- Functional: you can change several function calls beginning on an IEnumerable.

  `db.CrCases.Where(predicate).OrderBy(sortExpression)`
- "SQL like": it really looks like an "unordered SQL".

  `from crCase in db.CrCases where condition orderby sortExpression select crCase`

The condition and sort expression in the first notation require lambda expressions ([you can see them in action here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56913/Lambda-Expression-in-C-3-0)). In the second case the condition is expressed.

Most of the queries can be written either way.

You'll usually use `var` to store the query, and materialize it later.

```
var query = from crCase in db.CrCases 
   where condition orderby sortExpression 
   select crCase
CrCase firstCase = query.Firts();
List<CrCase> cases = query.ToList();
```

There are several flavors of LINQ. They all look equal on the surface, but are translated into another thing. For example:

- LINQ to objects: it's the more general, an allows to make queries on collections. Tis is what you'll use for this particular case.
- LINQ to SQL: this allows to write queries in C# which are transalated to SQL queries in the underlying database
- LINQ to Entities: similar to the previous, but you make your queries to an Entity Framework model, and the queries are finally transalated to the DB

There are some others flavors of LINQ. And, in fact, you can create your own, but that's not easy.

Finally, you have to take into account that a LINQ query isn't executed until you materialize it. I.e. it's not executed until you try to get data from it (converting it `ToList()`, `ToArray()` or whatever, enumerating it, or accesing any of it's data `First()`, `Sum()`, `Count()`). Depending on the flavor, the executing can be running C# code (LINQ to objects) or run a SQL Query in a DB (LINQ to SQL) or whatever.

Here you have a great place to learn how to use LINQ:

[LINQ 101](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)